# vue submit button data

Tags: html, vue.js, vuejs2

Suppose I had this code

```
<main>
    <form>
        <input type="text" v-model="name"> 
        <button type="submit" @click="submit">
            Submit From Vue Property
        </button>
    </form>
</main>
```

And this the Vue code.

```
new Vue({
   el : 'main',
   data : {
       name : ''
   },
   methods : {
      submit(){

      }
   }
})
```

how to submit to server from Vue data property instead? That i used in submit method.

( honestly, my actual code is much complicated but the problem is same. How to submit Vue data property instead? )

Comment: Could not understand you completely. What do you mean by submit from data property?

Comment: i'm sorry before. 

I mean submit "this.name" or maybe "this.email" or another property I keep in Vue.

I want to save whatever user input first before submit them.

Comment: where do you want to save them. They get bound to the properties you initialized in data property as you are using `v-model`

Comment: yep, that's what I mean. Saved them first in data property.

Comment: that gets automatically done by `v-model` , you do not need to do anything more

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are looking for an ajax based solution, consider using a library called '[axios](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios)'. It lets you post/get data using urls much like jquery's get and post methods.

To use axios you need to first install axios using npm, `npm install axios --save`, import it using `import axios from axios` and use this in submit. The new code will look like below:

```
<main>
    <form @submit.prevent="submit">
        <input type="text" v-model="name"> 
         <button type="submit">
            Submit From Vue Property
        </button>
    </form>
</main>


new Vue({
   el : 'main',
   data : {
       name : ''
   },
   methods : {
      submit(){
          axios.post('/your-url', {name: this.name})
          .then(res => {
              // do something with res
          })
          .catch(err => {// catch error});
      }
   }
})
```

Comment: so not in the button, but in form tag instead?

Comment: thanks for your help. But can I now how if i'm not using ajax?

Comment: yeah, if you don't do that then on click the default behaviour of form will kick in and the page will just refresh

Comment: if you are not using ajax then there is not point of using vuejs, all you need to do is give the inputs a name and put method and action attributes on the form tag

Comment: @ShekharJoshi, i have a related question for you. i have a page rendered by django with a few form fields, but i also want to add a vue/veutify autocomplete components to the page. when submitting the form using the submit button (no axios or ajax) the vue autocomplete form field is not sent to the server.

Comment: Yes you can do that, Vue is a progressive framework and you can even use it like you use jQuery. Include Vue using a cdn and initialise a vueapp and write your own autocomplete logic, if any other autocomplete library is available via a cdn you can even use that.

Answer (score 3):

Here you can submit total formdata using vue variables.you can make api's using axios.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <form @submit.prevent="submitform">
       <input type="text" v-model="formdata.firstname"> 
       <input type="text" v-model="formdata.lastname"> 
       <input type="text" v-model="formdata.email"> 
       <input type="text" v-model="formdata.password"> 
       <button type="submit">
         Submitform
       </button>
    </form>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

import axios from 'axios'

export default {
  name: 'el',
  data () {
    return {
       formdata:{ firstname: '', lastname: '', email: '', password: '' }
       // this is formdata object to store form values
    }
  },
  methods: {
    submitform(){
      axios.post('/url', { this.formdata })
      .then(res => {
         // response
      })
      .catch(err => { 
         // error 
      })
  },
  mounted () {

  },
  components: {

  }
}
</script>
```